# Specify the number of characters to be matched using a variable

Tags: regex, r, text-extraction

I am using the following expression to extract part of a string:

```
part <- sub("(^[a-zA-Z]{2}).*$", "\\1", "My String", perl = T)
```

which yields

```
"My"
```

The problem is that I want to use a variable to specify the amount of repetition in the expression, thus instead of having

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

I want

```
^[a-zA-Z]{var}
```

Say

```
var <- 2

part <- sub("(^[a-zA-Z]{var}).*$", "\\1", "My String", perl = T)
```

yields

```
"My String"
```

Instead of

```
"My"
```

How can I tweak this expression so **var** can be read as **2** instead of **“var”**? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `sprintf` for this. It will raise an error if, say, `var` isn't a digit.

```
var <- 2
pat <- "(^[a-zA-Z]{%d}).*$"
pat <- sprintf(pat, var)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
part <- sub(paste(sep="","(^[a-zA-Z]{",var,"}).*$"), "\\1", "My String", perl=T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. 
Maybe I am missing something, but it is not working.  
paste("(^[a-zA-Z]{",var,"}).*$") 

returns 

paste("(^[a-zA-Z]{ 2 }).*$")

note the blanks in { 2 }

Comment: @user1913361, sorry, you have to add `sep=""`.

Answer (score 0):

If we preface a command with `fn$` from the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package then we can use `$var` to refer to variables that are to be substituted:

```
library(gsubfn)
var <- 2
fn$sub("(^[a-zA-Z]{$var}).*$", "\\1", "My String")
```

or use `strapplyc` from the same package in which case the regular expression can be simplified:

```
fn$strapplyc("My String", "^[a-zA-Z]{$var}", simplify = TRUE)
```

I assume this is just an example and the real problem is more complex but if this is the real problem then it is easier and might be good enough to just use `substring`:

```
var <- 2
substring("My String", 1, var)
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked very well too. I'll take a closer look to the gsubfn library.